# itemRenderer is getting changed in the rows of a MX datagrid when scrolling

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, datagrid, itemrenderer

I am having a bad time with this itemRenderer.
I have an MX DataGrid that I am using to show some data I am collecting with an HTTP service. I wanted to show some data as a "preview" in the first column and I adding an itemRenderer with DataGridColum.itemRenderer property. Everything here works fine.

```
<mx:DataGrid id="labelsGrid" width="100%" height="100%" visible="false" 
 variableRowHeight="true" sortableColumns="false">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Preview" dataField="recordid"
         width="{ preview_column_width }" itemRenderer="us.lbs.itemRenderers.preview"/>

        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Design id" dataField="label_id" />

        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Font size" dataField="label_minheight"/>

        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Width" dataField="label_width"/>

        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Height" dataField="label_height"/>

        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Label P/N" dataField="label_pn"/> 

        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Font type" dataField="label_fonttype"/>

        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Qty" dataField="label_qty"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

and here is my code for the itemRenderer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:HBox xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
     width="100%" height="100%"
     horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" creationComplete="init( )">
<fx:Style> 
    @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
</fx:Style>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import aw.utils.StringUtils;

        import flashx.textLayout.edit.SelectionFormat;
        import flashx.textLayout.formats.TextLayoutFormat;

        import mx.binding.utils.BindingUtils;
        import mx.binding.utils.ChangeWatcher;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.CloseEvent;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.events.ModuleEvent;
        import mx.geom.RoundedRectangle;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
        import mx.messaging.messages.IMessage;
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.utils.ColorUtil;
        import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;
        import mx.utils.StringUtil;

        import spark.components.Application;

        import us.lbs.viewer;

                  public var dad:viewer = null;
                  public var zoom:int = 2;

                  public var px_in:Number = 96;
                  public var pt_px:Number = 1.333333333333333;

        [Bindable]public var var_width:Number = 0;
        [Bindable]public var var_height:Number = 0;
        [Bindable]public var var_font_size:Number = 12;
        [Bindable]public var tmp_lines:String = "";

        public function init( ):void {
            settingDad( ); setSize( ); setFontSize( ); fixLines( );
        }

        protected function settingDad():void {
            dad = this.parentDocument as viewer;
            if ( typeof( dad.previewers[ data.label_id ] ) != 'object' ) {
                dad.previewers[ data.label_id ] = {};
                dad.previewers[ data.label_id ].preview = this;

                /*Alert.show( 
                    this.data.label_id + "\n" + 
                    "Type: " + typeof( dad.previewers[ data.label_id ].preview ), 
                    this.data.rm_pn
                );*/
            }
        }

        protected function setFontSize( ):void {
            var_font_size = data.label_minheight * pt_px * zoom;
            var_font_size = Math.round( var_font_size );
        }

        protected function setSize( ):void {
            var_width  = Number( data.label_width ) * px_in * zoom;
            var_height = Number( data.label_height ) * px_in * zoom;

            dad.labelsGrid.visible = true;
            dad.preview_column_width = ( var_width > dad.preview_column_width ) ? var_width:dad.preview_column_width;
        }

        protected function fixLines( ):void {
            tmp_lines = ""; var lines:Array = String( data.lines ).split( "//" );
            for each ( var line:String in lines ) {
                tmp_lines += StringUtils.trim( line ) + "\n";
            } tmp_lines = StringUtils.trim( tmp_lines );
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:HGroup >
    <s:RichEditableText
        id="previewTxt" 
        backgroundColor="white"
        text="{ tmp_lines }" 
        selectionHighlighting="always" editable="false" selectable="true"
        width="{ var_width }" height="{ var_height }" 
        kerning="on"
        fontSize="{ var_font_size }" fontFamily="{ data.label_fonttype }"
        paddingTop="0" paddingBottom="0" paddingLeft="0" paddingRight="0"
        textAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" focusedTextSelectionColor="0xA8C6EE"
        selectionChange="dad.previewTxtSelectionChange(event)" />   
</s:HGroup>
```

The code I shared with you above is generating this ( which is good ):

[image: this is what I am expecting]

So, my issue here is that when  I scroll down the datagrid, I am getting the Previews changed, like this:

[image: the second preview gets changed]

The only value that has changed is the first column, everything is like it was before scrolling.

Why is happening this?
Sorry if I haven't written enough details, I think this is enough... but ask me if more details are needed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renderization uses a buffer, so you must link directly your property and its change.

Try this:

Link text property to fixLines method, as follow

in `<s:RichEditableText>` put in the property `text` this:

```
text = "{fixLines(data)}"
```

Change your method as follow:

```
protected function fixLines(obj:Object):String {
    if (obj == null) return "";
    var currText = "";
    var lines:Array = String( obj.lines).split( "//" );
    for each ( var line:String in lines ) {
        currText += StringUtils.trim( line ) + "\n";
    }
    currText = StringUtils.trim( tmp_lines );
    return currText;
}
```

In your init method, where you call fixLines, change as follow:

```
public function init( ):void {
    settingDad( ); setSize( ); setFontSize( ); fixLines(data);
}
```

Tell me if it's OK

Comment: Yes, it is ok. Now I have to find out how to keep the changes I am doing and avoid lose them when I am scrolling ( because, when scrolling is made, it re-renderize the itemRenderer ) is there a property to avoid re-render the itemRenderer? @joe-taras

Comment: Hi, when you bind correctly, the changes remain in memory in data object (linked with dataProvider of DataGrid). In the worst case, you can save the row when you goes out from row, but I think you can take your changes without problem